# I have this code, but when I compile it txt file remains empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ff = open('brojevi.txt','w')
for k in [i*j for i in range(4,5) for j in range (5,3,-1)]:
      ff.writelines('{}.'.format(k))
```

What numbers should be saved in txt file after compiling code? Tried compiling it but txt file remains empty...

Comment: Python is not a compiled language.

Comment: Run it. Don't compile.

Comment: ok, after running code...

Answer (score 0):

I saved your script under the name `script.py`.

I ran it with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4:

```
python2 script.py
```

```
python3 script.py
```

Both commands resulted in a file named `brojevi.txt` in the same directory as `script.py`. In addition, the content of this file is:

```
20.16.
```

Conclusion: your script works fine on Python 2.7 and 3.4.

---

As a side note, you should close files you open, either by calling the `close` method, or even better, by embedding your processing in a `with...as`, as follows:

```
with open('brojevi.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(...)
```

To stay simple, the `with` statement will create a context where `f` exists as a file. When this context is left, Python will destroy `f` the clean way, so you don't have to do it by yourself.